# Stopping and starting tasks using CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, cancellationtokensource

this is just a simplified version of what I am trying to do

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PrintButtonText("None");
    }

    private void PrintButtonText(string buttonText)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update!");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Button Pressed Text: " + buttonText);
            }
        }, tokenSource.Token);
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        PrintButtonText("Button1");
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        PrintButtonText("Button2");
    }
}
```

After I do

```
tokenSource.Cancel();
PrintButtonText("Button1");
```

It's not able to start the task again and continue to print my line. I need it to work this way for my program.

I want to stop the thread and start it again with some different parameters. How can I achieve this? thanks

**EDIT**:

Since I didn't get a solution with my simplified version, here is full code and what I am trying to do. Basically, on wpf window camera rendering starts on start. There is a button to start saving to file, but in order to save I have to update the config and start "pipeline" again.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline(); // Create and config the pipeline to sream color and depth frames.
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private bool saveDataToFile = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Config cfg = SetupConfig(false);
        PipelineProfile pp = pipeline.Start(cfg);
        StartRenderFrames(pp);
    }

    private void StartRenderFrames(PipelineProfile pp)
    {
        Colorizer colorizer = new Colorizer(); // The colorizer processing block used to visualize the depth frames.

        // Allocate bitmaps for rendring. Since the sample aligns the depth frames to the color frames, both of the images will have the color resolution
        using (var p = pp.GetStream(Stream.Color) as VideoStreamProfile)
        {
            imgColor.Source = new WriteableBitmap(p.Width, p.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
            imgDepth.Source = new WriteableBitmap(p.Width, p.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
        }
        Action<VideoFrame> updateColor = UpdateImage(imgColor);
        Action<VideoFrame> updateDepth = UpdateImage(imgDepth);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Wait for the next available FrameSet
                using (var frames = pipeline.WaitForFrames())
                {
                    var colorFrame = frames.ColorFrame.DisposeWith(frames);
                    var depthFrame = frames.DepthFrame.DisposeWith(frames);

                    // We colorize the depth frame for visualization purposes, .
                    var colorizedDepth = colorizer.Process(depthFrame).DisposeWith(frames);

                    // Render the frames.
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, updateDepth, colorizedDepth);
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, updateColor, colorFrame);
                }
            }
        }, tokenSource.Token);
    }

    private Config SetupConfig(bool saveDepthFile)
    {
        Config cfg = new Config();
        cfg.EnableStream(Stream.Depth, 640, 480, framerate: 15);
        cfg.EnableStream(Stream.Color, 640, 480, format: Format.Rgb8, framerate: 15);
        if (saveDepthFile)
        {
            cfg.EnableRecordToFile(@"C:\temp\My_test111.bag");
        }
        return cfg;
    }

    static Action<VideoFrame> UpdateImage(Image img)
    {
        var wbmp = img.Source as WriteableBitmap;
        return new Action<VideoFrame>(frame =>
        {
            using (frame)
            {
                var rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height);
                wbmp.WritePixels(rect, frame.Data, frame.Stride * frame.Height, frame.Stride);
            }
        });
    }

    private void StartSaving_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        pipeline.Stop();
        // This is where I have a problem. Rendering thread does not stop before I want to start again.
        Config cfg = SetupConfig(true);
        PipelineProfile pp = pipeline.Start(cfg);
        StartRenderFrames(pp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cancelling != pausing.  You can't restart a cancelled Task.  Use something besides a cancellation token to pause progress.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by that?

Comment: How can I completely stop/clean the task and start it again with new parameters? I haven't showed the complete code here for simplicity. Just want to understand how to reuse the same task code again as new.

Comment: Add `tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();` inside `PrintButtonText` before `Task.Factory...`.

Comment: Thanks that works! But does that mean the old task is stopped too and not using memory in the background?

Comment: Actually just by putting tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); inside PrintButtonText doesn't work. It seems the old threads are still running and printing old buttonText as well

Comment: @golu - Can you please post the complete code? I think you've made this too simple.

Comment: You must not call `tokenSource.Dispose`! What if (more than likely) `tokenSource` is dosposed while the thread is sleeping? Since you changed the code from your initial code I vote to close this question as `Unclear what you're asking`...

Comment: _"I want to stop the thread and start it again with some different parameters"_ -- why don't you just do that then? There are plenty of posts on this site explaining how to a) cleanly signal a thread to exit, and b) start a thread with specific parameters. So, what exactly is it that's giving you a problem? (Other than you apparently insisting on trying to reuse an object that's, by design, not reusable.)

Comment: I have updated the actual code I am working with. Hope someone can help.

Comment: So your problem is that you're restarting too fast? After calling `Cancel` wait for the cancellation to finish: `WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { tokenSource.Token.WaitHandle });`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IObservable<string> button1Clicks =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => button1.Click += h, h => button1.Click -= h)
                .Select(ep => "Button1");

        IObservable<string> button2Clicks =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => button2.Click += h, h => button2.Click -= h)
                .Select(ep => "Button2");

        IDisposable subscription =
            button1Clicks
                .Merge(button2Clicks)
                .StartWith("None")
                .Select(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500.0)).Select(n => x))
                .Switch()
                .ObserveOn(this)
                .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    }
```

That's the entire code needed to make what you want to work.

The only thing that you need to do is move `subscription` out into a `private` field and then simply call `subscription.Dispose()` to shut this all down.

This is much simpler than messing with cancellation tokens.

Comment: Hi, I am quite intrigued by this reactive functionality (I hadn't viewed it before). Any recommended tutorials or resources?